# Unsure why there's an 'undefined' header in Bootstrap 4 list

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to find out why there is an 'undefined' in the OL I have in the screenshot below. I would like to remove it. Can anyone assist me in figuring out why this is happening?

[image: screenshot of HTML code]

JavaScript:

```
        var letsReview;
        $.each(parsedData, function (index, item) {

            letsReview += "<li id='reviewID_" + item.ReviewID + "' class='list-group-item 
            reviewMaterial'><p>" + item.Review + "</p></li>";

            // print list of types
            $('#reviewContent').html(letsReview);
        });
```

Comment: You haven;t initialised `letReview` hence its value was `undefined`. And inside loop you are concatenating list items to `undefined` value. Initialising `letsReview` with empty string will solve your issue.
`var letsReview = ''`

Comment: @MohitKhandelwal yes ! that worked. awesome. thank you, Mohit.